# SU questions slowly turning into SO ones

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, superuser

I ask questions like "What program should I use to do ..." or "How to do ...", often keeping in mind that I can (and going to) write it myself if there is no such program.

Then I or someone proposes a script (with further discussions about that script), someone another proposes modified script and so on.

The question is definitely morphed from SU to SO one.

Also (after discussion of all that scripts) someone posts the answer like "Just use program xxx" which solves the problem without all that hacky scripts, so the question is in SU domain again.

What should I do? Should I try to migrate question to SO when it gets in it's domain (and back to SU when it exits the domain)? Should I ask questions SO right away if I'm going to implement it in case of non-answer?

Comment: examples, examples, examples.

Comment: 1. http://superuser.com/questions/168378/intelligent-subtraction-of-one-text-logfile-from-another 2. http://superuser.com/questions/153630/running-commands-in-parallel-with-a-limit-of-simultaneous-number-of-commands/168201

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What matters is that the original question is suited for Super User.

If the solution given involves programming, it's ok. If you want more details on the programming part, then you should ask a separate question on Stack Overflow like Ladybug suggested.

Keep in mind though that scripting is on topic on Super User. The site is targeted to "computer enthusiasts and power users". Scripting questions can be answered there. It's not just a place to tell you which program to use.

Comment: +1 You beat me to it. Was half way though writing a "surely it depends on only the question, not the answers" response myself. As an aside, if the question is edited to become more programmatic, then it might warrant shifting to SO?

Comment: @DMA - usually in this case I would suggest that the user revert his question to remain on-topic on SU (so it can still receive answers from it), and ask a new programming related version on SO.

Comment: You're right, that makes more sense. They can cross-link from/to thier new SO question to provide context if needed anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If someone answers "Use this script" and you have trouble with this script, why don't you ask a separate question about the script on SO? No need to shift the question around domains.

Answer (score 1):

Scripting is on topic on Super User. Power users should be encouraged to script.

How about this guideline? *Now edited as inspired by Gnoupi.*

- Writing a script for **yourself alone** as a "computer enthusiast/power user"?

  - Belongs on *Super User*.
- Writing a script for **other people** or for yourself as a programmer or a sysadmin?

  - Belongs on *Stack Overflow* or *Server Fault*.

Comment: Writing a script for other people could as well be Server fault, then ;)

Comment: And anyway, it's more a matter of "what for" than complexity. Enough with the idea that SU is for "simple things".

Comment: @Gnoupi. Good point about Server Fault, thanks: I will edit. Regarding complexity, I meant that if you spend **years** developing the "script", it's probably beyond the scope of Super User. Perhaps you're right and I should take that out too.